# Регулярное выражение - Положительные числа с плавающей точкой с ограничениями по длине

Tags: javascript, node.js, регулярные-выражения

Требуется валидировать число с плавающей точкой, с ограничением по длине до точки в 6 символов и после точки в 8 символов.

Также требуется отсекать кучу нолей вначале. Пропускать только если в начале один 0.

Пропускать целые числа. То есть точка и далее необязательно. Но если точки нету то длина не более 6 символов.

Пробовал вот такое:

```
^(0|[1-9]\d{1,5})([.]?[0-9]{0,8})?$
```

Но не совсем подходит.

Числа, которые должны проходить, для примера:

- 1
- 0.00000001
- 123456
- 123456.12345678

И которые проходить не должны:

- 000,1
- 0
- 00
- 1234567
- 0.123456789

Comment: А `0` почему нет?

Comment: @vp_arth Ну по условиям он мне тоже не нужен)

Comment: Ок, не нужен, так не нужен)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По сути, ваша регулярка почти готова. Только с квантификаторами запутались немного..

```js
const r = /^(?:0(?!$)|[1-9]\d{0,5})(\.\d{1,8})?$/

const tests = [
  '1',
  '0.00000001',
  '123456',
  '123456.12345678',

  '000,1',
  '000.1',
  '0',
  '00',
  '1234567',
  '0.123456789',

// Не специфицированы:
  '1.00000000', // +
  '2.',         // -
  '.5',         // -
];

tests.forEach(test => {
  console.log(test, r.test(test));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(0\.(\d{0,8})|((?!0)\d{1,6})(\.\d{0,8})?)$
```